# How to use $_POST in another file

Tags: php

I am making a panel with PHP. It contains a login script. It's working good, just what I expect. The next step is: Echo the username.

With `$_POST` you can echo the username what the person has typed. So, just like: Welcome, `$username`.

The problem now is, that I can't echo the `$_POST`. It's not possible because you will redirect to another page. My question is: How can I echo a username.

My login script:

```
<?php
//DATABASE CONNECTION
session_start();  
$host = "localhost";  
$username = "root";  
$password = "root";  
$database = "test_tutorial";  
$message = "";  

try  {  
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

    $fname = $_POST["fname"];

    //LOGIN CHECK
    if(isset($_POST["login"]))  {  
        if(empty($_POST["fname"]) || empty($_POST["lname"]))  {  
            echo 'All fields required';  
        }  
        else  
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname = :fname AND lname = :lname";  
            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);  
            $statement->execute(  
                array(  
                    'fname'     =>     $_POST["fname"],  
                    'lname'     =>     $_POST["lname"]  
                )  
            );
            $count = $statement->rowCount();  
            if($count > 0)  
            {  
                //VISITED
                header("Refresh:0; url=veilig.php");
                //END
            }
            else  
            {  
                echo 'Wrong data'; 
            }
        }
    }
}  
catch(PDOException $error)  {  
    $message = $error->getMessage();  
}
?>
```

My form:

```
<form action="" method="post">  
    <label>fname</label>  
    <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" />  
    <br />  
    <label>lname</label>  
    <input type="password" name="lname" class="form-control" />  
    <br />  
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />  
</form>
```

So, how can I echo a post if someone is redirected to another page?

Comment: You can send it as a `GET` parameter, you can set it in session.

Comment: You store the user data in a session which you then can use where ever you need it.

Comment: I would also recommend redirecting the user with: `header('Location: veilig.php');` instead and add an `exit;` after that header (to stop the script from continuing being parsed).

Comment: even with a prepared statement, this looks unsafe. You are planning on adding a password field and hashed, right?

Comment: @Kisaragi Putting the data (*username*) into a session is fine, but there is no good reason to make it into a `GET` request. It creates security vulnerabilities, it's especially not recommended for username and passwords.

Comment: @magnusEriksson Yes, right

Comment: I'd recommend the session instead of a GET.  You don't want this type of information in the querystring.

Comment: I'd use the database you already seem to have, just have the username and sessions there. No need to waste memory on sessions.

Comment: What if there are multiple "John Smith"s ?

Comment: Thank you, I used the Session and it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already called `session_start` so you're ready to use the [`$_SESSION` superglobal](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) which will persist data for the user across all pages that call `session_start` first.

For example, here on `index.php`

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = 'Prabhjot.Singh';

header('Location: veilig.php');
```

Then later on `veilig.php`

```
<?php

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

> Prabhjot.Singh